# How can I find equationts for the EM field $E=(E_x,E_y,0)$ and $B=(0,0,B_z)$?

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, electromagnetism

I am trying to find the motion's equation for a charged particle $q$ with mass $m$ in an EM field. First the 2 equations I have are:
$$\frac{\mathrm dU_x}{\mathrm dt}= W_cU_y + \frac{W_cE_x}{B_z}\\
\frac{\mathrm dU_y}{\mathrm dt}= -W_cU_x + \frac{W_cE_y}{B_z}$$
After I use a new complex variable $U'= U_x + \mathrm iU_y$, I come up with the differential equation
$$\frac{\mathrm dU'}{\mathrm dt} + \mathrm iW_cU'= \frac{W_c}{B_z}(E_x+\mathrm iE_y),$$
which gives us
$$U'= u_o*e^i*(-W_c-d) - i*E_x/B_z + E_y/B_z.$$so

$u_x(t)= u_o*\cos(-W_c-d) + E_y/B_z$

$u_y(t)= u_o*\sin(-W_c-d) - E_x/B_z$

I have come up with these 2 by integrate the previous

$X(t)= -u_o/W_c*(\sin(-W_c*t-d) + t*E_y/B_z + x_o$

$Y(t)= u_o/W_c*(\cos(-W_c*t-d) - t*E_x/B_z +y_o$

uo,xo,yo,d,Ex,Ey,B are known obv and $W_c=\dfrac{qB_z}{m}$.

please any help would be nice!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: ok, i ll try to fix it

Comment: i hope its better now